# HB RFID attack. What am I missing?

Tags: security, cryptography, rfid

Regarding the RFID protocol HB (not HB+) I am having a hard time understanding why my approach will not work.

So in HB we have the Tag and the Reader whom both share a secret X.

We are trying to figure out X.

The protocol goes as follow:
[image]

Lets suppose k = 3 bits.
From the papers I have read it seems the attack goes as follows.
set a = 001 and send say 1000 times
set a = 010 and send 1000 times
set a = 100 and send 1000 times

take the parity which comes out the majority of times for each a revealing x.

This makes sense to me and works fine.

My question is, why can I not simply set a to 001. Since a = 001 when it is ANDED with x it will always produce x which will then be XOR with v. The resulting Z will always be either x    or it will be x XOR with 1.   We then just take the output that happens the majority of the times which would be x since the prob of v = 1 < .5

I feel like I would only have to run this say 10 times rather then running every a multiple times.

Am i missing an important aspect of this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why can I not simply set *a* to '001'?**

*x* and *a* are of length *k*, so

*x* = { *x*<sub>*k*-1</sub>, ..., *x*<sub>0</sub> }
   *a* = { *a*<sub>*k*-1</sub>, ..., *a*<sub>0</sub> }

If, *k* = 3, this would be

*x* = { *x*<sub>2</sub>, *x*<sub>1</sub>, *x*<sub>0</sub> }
   *a* = { *a*<sub>2</sub>, *a*<sub>1</sub>, *a*<sub>0</sub> }

I.e. *x* and *a* would be one of '000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', or '111'.

So the scalar product *x* • *a* results in

*x* • *a* = (*x*<sub>2</sub> AND *a*<sub>2</sub>) XOR (*x*<sub>1</sub> AND *a*<sub>1</sub>) XOR (*x*<sub>0</sub> AND *a*<sub>0</sub>)

Consequently using *a* = '001' results in

*z* = *x* • '001' = (*x*<sub>2</sub> AND '0') XOR (*x*<sub>1</sub> AND '0') XOR (*x*<sub>0</sub> AND '1') = *x*<sub>0</sub>

So you would not get the remaining digits of *x* (i.e. *x*<sub>2</sub> and *x*<sub>1</sub>) in that case. Similarly, if you use an *a* with more than one bit set, e.g. *a* = '111', you would get

*z* = *x* • '111' = (*x*<sub>2</sub> AND '1') XOR (*x*<sub>1</sub> AND '1') XOR (*x*<sub>0</sub> AND '1') = *x*<sub>2</sub> XOR *x*<sub>1</sub> XOR *x*<sub>0</sub>

and therefore could dervice the digits of *x*. Thus, you need to perform the protocol with *a* = '001', *a* = '010', and *a* = '100' in order to get each digit of *x*.

**I feel like I would only have to run this say 10 times rather then running every a multiple times.**

Well, for every round, you will get a correct result with a probability *v*. So the expected value would be

E[X] = *v*, if the correct digit is a '1', and
   E[X] = 1 - *v*, if the correct digit is a '0'.

Hence, the mean value over all rounds (i.e. every sample you take) will **approximate** *v* for a '1' and will **approximate** 1 - *v* for a '0' for an **infinite** number of rounds. But this does not necessarily mean that you already reach this expected value after 1 round or 10 rounds. However, with every round you increase the confidence of getting the expected value.